# Why Meta Reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, meta, meta-reputation

The meta reputation is kind of strange. If you don't keep track of it you don't know where it comes from, if you recognized it all since it's not tracked like on the main site, where the $\nabla$ pop up left to your name tells you where it came from. OK there are some queries like this one

> [A Users total Rep ON META if there was no reputation cap](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematicsmeta/query/76335/a-users-total-rep-on-meta-if-there-was-no-reputation-cap)

(haha, *if there was no reputation cap*) but there are some things I'd like to ask (for):

1. Can we display the current meta rep below the main rep on the meta user pages?
2. ...or a Reputation tab on the meta user page?
3. Can the meta notification system work like the main one?
4. Do tag wiki edits give +1 meta rep?
5. What can I do with my meta rep? There are no bounties to use it :-(

Comment: meta.SO: [SE 2.0 Meta doesn't award rep, but it refers to “rep”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66370/183484)

Comment: @MartinSleziak the NOT-accepted answer says: *Reputation is awarded on metas, it's just not shown next to your name in the top bar (the rep from the parent site is shown instead) -- but that "reputation" is still a valid measure of your participation in that meta.*

Answer (score 5):

Meta reputation is synchronized every hour from the reputation on the main site. There is no real meta reputation, your actions on the meta site have no influence on the reputation value.

(There is one exception and that is Meta.SO, the meta site for Stackoverflow and the whole network)

Comment: So why does it say "+x" in the votes? What for?

Comment: @draks... It just counts the votes, but you do not gain reputation from those votes.

Comment: I think I remember that I've seen the candidates meta reputation during the last election: http://math.stackexchange.com/election/3 ,  ahh I see "Meta Participation"...

Comment: @MadScientist There's [indirect evidence](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/7092/53153) that per-site metas have internal count of meta reputation, like a vestigial organ.

Comment: Would be interesting to see whether mortar board really works at meta... Anyway call it what you want, but I think showing it would contribute nicely to the gaming factor at meta... What about the tag wiki edits?

Comment: @draks... [Mortarboard does work on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=53153). I got it when History of MSE was upvoted a bunch of times in a single day. You can try guessing what the other 13 users did to earn the honor.

Comment: @5PM Wow. Did you get it only for the History post, when it reached 40 votes (= 200 meta rep?) or with less than 40?

Comment: @drake No, history was just one of the factors, I think.

Comment: @MadScientist so it's evident (at least to me) that it's tracked somewhere. Why can't it be displayed?